# How to start a GUI app in another tty

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xorg

I use Blender and some of the shortcuts are being interfered with by elementary OS. So, I'd like to run Blender on elementary OS on another tty.

I've tried this so far, but X won't start:

```
startx -display :2 -- :2 vt1
```